# How to realize a Newsletter system with Rss news feed?

Tags: php, mysql, rss, newsletter

I have a news portal with everyday news. My need is to send through newsletter the daily news to subscribers.

I've already realized a PHP/MySQL custom newsletter system that performs the following tasks:

- fetches the daily news
- fetches the list of users who want the newsletter
- everynight through a cronjob I launch a script that performs the above every 5 minutes sending the newsletter to 10 recipients at a time each cycle

**Problems:**

1. I have to estimate how long this cronjob needs to run in order to complete the full list of users (5' x 10 emails) = 120Email/hours = TotalUsers/emailperhours = number of hours the cronjob needs to run
   I overcome this problem because I don't have so much users until now and I can still manage to make the cronjob run enough to send all mails, but for the future?
2. All email receievers are saved double opt-in, means I'm quite sure of their existence, but it happens how you can imagine that I'll have anyway many Mail delivery for other reasons:
   here I need help because I dunno how to catch there Mail delivery through PHP and update MySQL tables in order to suspend these unnnecessary sendings.

**Alternatives:**
I know that there are many providers who offer Newsletter systems but this works fine every time u go and compile your static email body. Here I need a  dynamic email body to be generated every day with fresh news and then send it to recipients.
Still here I need some advice.

Comment: I've found there's the IMAP php extension, and I've already setup a script that scans my inbox for Mail delivery and generates for me the MySQL update to remove those recipients that returns more than X times.

Answer (score 0):

You might find it worthwhile using a service like [SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/substitution_tags.html) -  they have an API that handles dynamic content. I haven't tested it out that aspect myself, but for the small price they charge it might be worth saving you the headache.

Comment: I have already a Newsletter service that implements this substitution Tag functionality, but actually I hope there was a quicker way: like set up a template that may call a script to build the email body before sending the email... Like my scripts do...

Comment: Okay - got it. Sounds like you want something in PHP. Not sure if it exists or if you'll have to build something yourself...

Comment: I have built it already as I said above. Actually I also added an accessory script to read the returned mail delivery and cleanup the mail list. What I'd like to improve is the scheduling part. Actually my sending script sends 10 emails per execution via cronjob. The cronjob is executed for X hours. but as happened before as the mail list grows I may encounter the problem that not all emails are sent and cronjob daily executions schedule ends...